# Library to populate HTML templates from objects and/or JSON

Tags: java, html, parsing, templates, mustache

I would like to build HTML templates with some kind of tags and have parser that will populate it with data from my source. I get data as JSON and/or POJO.

Any suggestions on such parser? SOmething simple and light is what I need. So far I know about Java Mustache. Is that the best out there?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to do the substitution in the browser, i.e. in your html page you make an ajax request that receives a json object and you then want to replace portions of your html with whatever is in that object then you can use javascript templating, like [jqote2](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/). I've used it and had good luck.

If you are looking to make the substitutions on the java side from a pojo, before sending the html to the browser then there are plenty of options like jsp, freemarker, and velocity